# Checkbox outside of form

Tags: php, javascript

Because of a design requirement, I need to place several checkboxes outside of a form.  Is it still possible to include these values in the form's submit action? Maybe with javascript or some other way I'm not thinking of?

Comment: NO, you will need to include within form only....

Comment: keep in mind you can do `<body><div><form ...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use HTML5 there is a `form` attribute for that. See the following example:

```
<p>
  <input type="email" form="my_form" />
</p>
<form id="my_form">
  <input type="submit" name="Send">
</form>
```

This should work in all modern browsers. No javascript required.

Comment: Although this is a valid no JS answer, I think you're going to run into a lot more people that have browsers that don't support HTML5 than people with JS disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be accomplished using Javascript, but not by using solely PHP.

You'll have to place your form elements as you need, and then collect the inputs using Javascript when the trigger (likely a submit button) is pressed. You can then use Ajax to submit the form to PHP.

Placing the elements outside of your form tags certainly makes things trickier though (you won't be able to use the `serialize()` function). So if you could avoid it, you'd have a much simpler task.

Comment: Note: this only works if JavaScript is enabled, so try to get the checkbox somehow into the form element.

Comment: Good note @Hippo, I should have had that in my answer. So yes, if you're looking for a 100% solution that includes users with JS disabled, you have to put the checkboxes within the form or you're out of luck.