# HTML form fields outside of form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I have a dynamically generated website that calls the user's attention to missing data which they can update using an appropriate input type depending on what data is missing. These fields are also displayed elsewhere in the website as part of an overview of the object they are examining where they are also editable.

Wrapping the main content in `<form> ... </form>` works but messes with some of the aesthetics like accordions etc. And arguably, may be bad form.

Using the HTML5 attribute `form="myform"`, as suggested in [Checkbox outside of form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821764/checkbox-outside-of-form)  would have been ideal were [IE not so behind the times](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-attribute).

To my knowledge, this now leaves me with JavaScript.

My question then is what is the appropriate way to implement the JS solution. Should I first create the form and hide it and then reference its elements and submission? Are there other options?

The back-end, if relevant, is Flask.

Comment: Are you using JQuery?

Comment: I have no constraints on scripting languages. Just trying to figure out the best way to implement it.

Comment: You can have an `onchange` event on the input and using the event change a hidden input in the form.

Comment: So solution: instantiate the form outside of the main content, hide it, then - as you've suggested - onchange update the value stored in the hidden form and likewise for any buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but, you could create the inputs without a wrapping `<form>` and send the data with JavaScript using $.ajax({}), fetch, or whatever you are using.

HTML

```
<div id="form-noform">
  <input type="text" id="whatevs">
  <input type="text" id="foshizzle">
  <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript (Using jQuery for simplicity)

```
$('#submit-button').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // not sure if this is needed.

  $.ajax({
    url: '/yourendpoint/',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      whatevs: $('#whatevs').val(),
      foshizzle: $('#foshizzle').val()
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This could work well. As a jquery newbie, is it possible to to dynamically populate the ajax data by tag?

Comment: @Vunderbar you can put whatever you want on the data object at the moment of event ("click" in this example). So yes, I think, i'd need to see a little more context of what you mean

Comment: This ended being the more efficient solution. Using ` $("[dataform='mform']").each(function (){
  id = $(this).attr("id");
  data[id] = $(this).val();
  });` to generate the data field.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You cand a data-form to your controls outside the form, then, before make a post to your form, for every control in with this data attribute create a hidden input element inside the form with it's name and value.

```
function postDynamicForm(formId){
    $("#" + formId + " [data-generated='true']").remove();
    $("[data-form='" + formId + "'']").each(function (){
        $("#" + formId).append("<hidden data-generated='true' name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "' value='" + $(this).val() "'");
    });

    $("#" + formId).submit();
}
```

Dont submit the form with a input of type submit, just call this function with the form id. This function remove already generated hiddens before add the new ones.

Use a code like this for an input outside the form:

```
<input type='text' data-form='form1' value='aaa'/>
```

This input will be an hidden input element inside the form1 form **in the future post action**.

Comment: As the input elements may be duplicated across sections, I will need to use  `blur` to make sure the values are consistent and and not apply the tag to the elements in the section that draws the users attention to the missing values?

Comment: No, you dont need to do blur. When you call this function, it remove old hiddens, then add new ones, and finally submits the form. You dont need to worry about consistency of data. The form always will submit the values of inputs outside.